# Generic response type based on input type

Tags: typescript

I try to write types for simple function `fun`.

Here are some interfaces for input and response:

```js
interface Input {
  test1?: true
  test2?: true
  test3?: true
}
interface Res {
  test1?: string
  test2?: string
  test3?: string
}
```

and the function itself

```js
fun(input: Input): Res {
    const res: Res = {}
    if (input.test1) {
      res.test1 = 'jupi'
    }
    if (input.test2) {
      res.test2 = 'jupiX2'
    }
    if (input.test3) {
      res.test3 = 'jupiX3'
    }
    return res
  }
```

With current types, the response of the function `fun` is garanted to be `Res` (as explicitly typed) regardless of the provided input. On the other hand, we can see that the implementation of `fun` will return values for each *key* that is passed in `input`.

The proposed solution for connecting input and response types is [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

My example would look like this:

```
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test1'>): Pick<Res, 'test1'>
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test2'>): Pick<Res, 'test2'>
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test3'>): Pick<Res, 'test3'>
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test1' | 'test2'>): Pick<Res, 'test1' | 'test2'>
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test1' | 'test3'>): Pick<Res, 'test1' | 'test3'>
fun(input: RequireMany<Input, 'test2' | 'test3'>): Pick<Res, 'test2' | 'test3'>
fun(input: Required<Input>): Required<Res>
fun(input: Input): Res {
  const res: Res = {}
  if (input.test1) {
    res.test1 = 'jupi'
  }
  if (input.test2) {
    res.test2 = 'jupiX2'
  }
  if (input.test3) {
    res.test3 = 'differentText'
  }
  return res
}
```

where `RequireMany` is

```
type RequireMany<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, Keys>>
```

I plan to have at least 7 keys in my `input`, so here comes my question:

**Is there a better way (some generic?) to type the `fun` than a lot of Function Overloads?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps do something like this with generics:

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvAsAKClYCAZ2AEYB+ALigCMB7OgGwgEM4oAfKROAEwgBmASzgReufIRIAmKrQbM2nbn0EixEgsWABmOfSat2XHv2GjxOAL65coSFABKxADwAVKBAAehPkVgIyAB8aJiaUmTUbgDaAOQRpLEAup4+EH7yhkrkUCQATiIA5lDUpmoWUAD0lVBsdMAAFhB5UHRgwEJ07E150EL+wHTcRNCxogBuzbFQIiSsvK0CULFl5mLT-JB8Ra3sIHSILYgjUADGLCPh2tJRcRHSyam+vP4Giuw5+TulqmuWktodLd4oDHt5nq8FEYoJ9gAU4MUfmZ1JYbDhcAIeKcOl0oJi4O4nukXgEkMAggAKERkqIASmoziI7hC2DwUF6wEO7FZ+HwADoBRSQSREjN2NTkDDMFoRdRYgArRBgITTKwlTBWWkAGk0-MFwuADzFYrJUowMsNcsVyoAGka1dQMJqdWy9XyhREdNMRCbJTlzZ65bwhAIBM10sA3ODVeqndrNGqLk5XG4grg0bhTl0iIY+Yw6IUKfiKQHtKRqHDENBNXyErSqjUGnRJvDis3mhbSLkmwB3AYNFgoITAWL+Xo5xiTBaDZZfBGxTPZ3P5wvF0uygh5KtQGv3evVC3SGb+Fa-FELnBZuATiB5gtFnglzsVrfV2m1wH7mqe4-LVbn3AgA)

```js
type Input = {
  test1?: boolean | undefined
  test2?: boolean | undefined
  test3?: boolean | undefined
}

type Res<T extends Input> = {
  test1: T['test1'] extends boolean ? string : undefined // another option here is to use 'never' instead of 'undefined' depending on your use case
  test2: T['test2'] extends boolean ? string : undefined
  test3: T['test3'] extends boolean ? string : undefined
}

function fun<T extends Input>(input: T): Res<T> {
  return {
    ...('test1' in input ? { test1: 'jupi' } : {}),
    ...('test2' in input ? { test2: 'jupiX2' } : {}),
    ...('test3' in input ? { test3: 'jupiX3' } : {}),
  } as Res<T>
}

console.log(fun({ test1: true }).test1) // hovering over test1 shows that it's resolved to 'string'
console.log(fun({ test1: true }).test2) // test2 is 'undefined'
console.log(fun({ test1: true }).test3) // test3 is 'undefined'
```